# Обфускация php проекта

Tags: php, обфускация

Всем привет. У меня есть проекты, которые я полностью отдаю заказчикам на некоммерческое пользование, т.е. без права изменения и продажи. Но понимаю, что это можно обойти довольно простым путем, поскольку весь бэкэнд хранится у них.

Думаю в сторону обфускаторов php, чтобы перед тем, как отдать весь код, скрипт прогонял все через углифаер и выдавал на выходе папку с проектом, где все, мягко говоря, не в лучшем виде, но в полностью рабочем.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? И кто как её решал?

ЗЫ нашел на ноде такой пакет https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-php думаю, что загнать туда рекурсивно все файлы, а аутпут делать в соседнюю директорию, которая потом и идет на продакшн. Из минусов: берет только названия переменных. Классы и функции не трогает.

Comment: ioncube, zend guard. а обычная обфускация, с сохранением исходного кода  бесполезна

Comment: обфускатор поможет слегка озадачить школьников, но это не панацея, его всегда есть возможность снять, просто один проще, другой сложнее. Для многих давно написаны универсальные деобфускаторы, для более сложных тоже написаны, но чаще не на паблике. Т.ч. если задаться целью, то вы больше потратите сил/времени на придумывание защиты php, чем злоумышленники на её снятие

Comment: А если в каждый файл добавить проверку на совпадение по хешу?